create_tool_calling_agent in Langchain only return tool result in json instead of a straightfoward answer

from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor, create_tool_calling_agent
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [("system", "You are a helpful Finance/Investment AI assistant."),
        ("placeholder", "{chat_history}"),
        ("human", "{input}"),
        ("placeholder", "{agent_scratchpad}"),]
)
tools = [get_income_statement_tool]
agent = create_tool_calling_agent(llm, tools, prompt)

agent_executor = AgentExecutor(agent=agent, tools=tools, verbose=True)
agent_executor.invoke({"input": "what is apple's revenue on 2022? give me a short answer"})

I built a create_tool_calling_agent that has the get_income_statement tool, which takes in company ticker,start_date, end_date and returns corresponding income statement data. when I asked "What is apple's revenue in 2022? ", the agent only returned me the data from the tools in JSON format instead of a text like' Apple's revenue in 2022 is xxxx'.( see picture) what went wrong, why can't the agent observer the tool result and return me a text with the answer of my question in it.
I expect the create_tool_calling_agent will return a straightfoward answer to me insteand of the tool result in JSON
see output from this picture
